# RESTful methods in IBM MobileFirst 8.0 adapters

Tags: rest, ibm-mobilefirst, restful-architecture, mobilefirst-adapters

I'm currently working iwth IBM MobileFirst 8.0 solution and I have found something curious that I'd like to ask/confirm with the community:

According to [documentation](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/it/foundation/8.0/adapters/javascript-adapters/js-http-adapter/), adapters only expose GET and POST methods, so any mobile application is able to execute this methods in their API calls... Anybody knows which is the reason for this? I mean, why is it not possible to define a DELETE or PUT method? IS there any security reason or similar for this?

Additionally, in procedure implementation, I'm not able to find if there is any distinction for invoking an specific API through GET or POST method. Procedures are implemented once in all examples I have found. Any idea about how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: They probably just went for the most commonly used methods as SOAP and HTML forms only supports POST and GET (as meintioned by Eric already). They may even have other reasons, who knows other then the devs of that service?! We can only speculate about them which will most likely attract opinionated answers. As there might not be a solid solution to the actual question it is a valid target for being closed actually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MFP 8.0's Javascript adapters only support GET and POST.

If you would like to use the other HTTP methods - PUT/DELETE , you can always use [Java adapters](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/it/foundation/8.0/adapters/java-adapters/).

Comment: Hi @VivinK, I hadn't realized that Java adapters allow the usage of PUT/DELETE methods. As architect of my solution, I'm looking for using a meaningful API solution and usage of a RESTful API was key objective (previously I had weird things like a GET/POST /editElement method which made me cry just looking at it...)

Answer (score 0):

Although they should, not all clients support `DELETE` and `PUT` operations. For instance, HTML forms only support `GET` and `POST`. If they want their services available to all clients, not just most, they need to make the entire API accessible through only those two verbs.